# jQuery - On active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I have a materlize collapsible list. What i want to do, is change the icon of the list item when someone clicks on it. My question is, how do i add an event listener that checks to see if you clicked on an li, and to only change that icon? The collapsible list adds a 'active' class to the li. However, when i try to listen for this change, no event is fired.

script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collapsible li").on('active', function(){
        console.log("found event"); 
    });
});
```

List

```
  <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`this` in jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_this). Also, how are you storing your icons for the `<li>`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collapsible li").on('click', function(){
        // *this* refers to the current element
        $(this).find('.material-icons').html('ICON_NAME');
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but it doesnt which the icons back. How could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collapsible").on('click', 'li.active', function(){
        console.log("found event"); 
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/84cvamd1/1/

Comment: I dont see found event in the console.

Comment: please check the jsfiddle i added.

Comment: That event is called when i click on text (drop down text) inside the li, not on the li element itself.

Comment: When you click any <li> for the first time, materialize adds #active to it and the text is shown. Then you can click on that <li> or the text inside. Both trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".collapsible li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass( "active" );
});
```